# create two button in one line in struts2

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, struts2

I have a form that have 2 buttons. one form register and another for cancel form. I create them with following code:

```
<s:submit name="cancel"  key="project.button.cancel" />
<s:submit name="login"  key="form.register.registerBtn" />
```

but I have a problem with its view. I will to command in one row. but it create two buttons in two row. you can see its picture in the following image:

[image]

how can I resolve this problem?
thanks.

**update 2013/9/21 :**
it is full jsp page code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/form.css" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top: 20px;"></div>
    <div style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="float: left; padding: 20px; padding-top: 0px;">
        <img alt=""
            src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/register.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="width: 300px; float: left;" id="col">
        <h1>
            <span class="title"><s:text name="form.register.title" /></span>
        </h1>
        <hr />
        <form action="login" method="post" namespace="/">
            <span class="text"><s:text name="user.nickname" /></span>
            <s:textfield name="nickname" />
            <hr />
            <span class="text"><s:text name="user.username" /></span>
            <s:textfield name="username" />
            <span class="text"><s:text name="user.password" /></span>
            <s:password name="password" />
            <span class="text"><s:text name="user.validation" /></span>
            <s:password name="validation" />
            <s:checkbox name="recoverable" key="user.recoverable" />
            <hr />
            <span class="text"><s:text name="user.email" /></span>
            <s:textfield name="validation" />
            <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: no-wrap;">
                <s:submit name="cancel" key="project.button.cancel"
                    cssClass="button-red" />
                <s:submit name="login" key="form.register.registerBtn"
                    cssClass="button-green" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing multiple submit buttons in the same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328645/placing-multiple-submit-buttons-in-the-same-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution to wrap them in one `div` tag and apply CSS

```
<s:form action="login" method="post" namespace="/" theme="simple">
  ....
  <div style="display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;">
    <s:submit name="cancel"  key="project.button.cancel" />
    <s:submit name="login"  key="form.register.registerBtn" />
  </div>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete JSP?

Comment: i add it at the end of my post